# Insert text at the center of a image

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, javafx-8

I have this code which inserts Image into the center of a borderpane:

```
private static final ImageView iv;    
    static {
        iv = new ImageView(StartPanel.class.getResource("/com/dx57dc/images/6.jpg").toExternalForm());
    }

bpi.setCenter(iv);
```

And now I have this problem. I have this insert text as a label at the center of the image.

Text inftx = new Text("Infrastructure");

How I can do this?

Comment: Have you tried using a StackPane?

Comment: Yes, but is there other way?

Comment: Why? That should have worked, no?

Comment: I prefer more simple approach if there is one.

Comment: Look at example 1-4 - it is not very complex: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/layout/builtin_layouts.htm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a [`StackPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/layout/builtin_layouts.htm#sthref10) to performed the desired image overlap. The following code can be used on your example:

```
private static final ImageView iv;    

static {
    iv = new ImageView(StartPanel.class.getResource("/com/dx57dc/images/6.jpg").toExternalForm());
    Text inftx = new Text("Infrastructure");
    StackPane pane = new StackPane();

    pane.getChildren().add(iv);
    pane.getChildren().add(inftx);

    pane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
}
```

As informed on [`StackPane` tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/layout/builtin_layouts.htm#sthref10):

> The StackPane layout pane places all of the nodes within a single stack with each new node added on top of the previous node. This layout model provides an easy way to overlay text on a shape or image or to overlap common shapes to create a complex shape.