# Add rectangle to image

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have a image which I would like to edit with JavaFX. How I could add almost transparent rectangle and text similar to the image below?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inset text at the center of a image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18165662/inset-text-at-the-center-of-a-image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `VBox` to wrap a `Label` or two and wrap that in a `Pane` or some other basic node. Style the label to get the desired text appearance, and style the highest node (the one wrapping your `VBox`) to have a semi-transparent background like so: `-fx-background-color: #000000a8;`. Change the last two characters ("a8") to achieve the desired level of transparency.